# I can't get my buttons to control the timer in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, button, actionlistener

I have this code :

```
public void initTimer() {

        timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
        alpha = 1f;
    }
```

which starts a blend of two images from one to another. i have added 3 buttons. Start Blend, Stop Blend and Save Image. This code is in one class called Frame.

```
public Frame() {

        loadImages();
        initTimer();

        pnlButton.add(btnStartBlend);
        this.add(pnlButton);
        pnlButton.add(btnStopBlend);
        this.add(pnlButton);
        pnlButton.add(saveImage);
        this.add(pnlButton);
    }

        public static void placeComponents (JFrame frame)  {
        frame.setLayout(null);  

        ActionListener btnStartBlendListener = (ActionListener) new BtnStartBlendListener();
        btnStartBlend.addActionListener(btnStartBlendListener);

        ActionListener btnStopBlendListener = (ActionListener) new BtnStopBlendListener();
        btnStopBlend.addActionListener(btnStopBlendListener);

        ActionListener saveImageListener = (ActionListener) new SaveImageListener();
        saveImage.addActionListener(saveImageListener);
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        MeSmaller1 = new ImageIcon("MeSmaller1.jpg").getImage();
        MeSmaller2 = new ImageIcon("MeSmaller2.jpg").getImage();
    }

    public void initTimer() {

        timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
        alpha = 1f;
    }
```

And this code in another class called pictureMorph:-

```
 public void initTimer() {
    int delay = 500;
    ActionListener btnStartBlend = new BtnStartBlendListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(BtnStartBlendListener e) {
              //...Perform a task...
          }
      };
```

I have also created 3 other classes for the buttons, all the same just with different headings related to the buttons:-

```
public class BtnStartBlendListener implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton btnStartBlend = (JButton) e.getSource();
}
}
```

So there is BtnStopListener .... and SaveImageListener as well. How can I get the buttons to do what I want, I am soo confused with this.

Regards,

Caroline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is an `ActionListener` for a button to start the timer, then this will do it:

```
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        initTimer();
    }
});
```

Let me know if this doesn't for-fill your requirements.

(Why are you creating an `ActionListener` inside `pictureMorph.initTimer()` methd though?)

---

### EDIT - Answer

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class Frame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Image MeSmaller1;
    private Image MeSmaller2;
    protected Timer timer;
    private float alpha;

    JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
    static JButton btnStartBlend = new JButton("Start Blend");
    static JButton btnStopBlend = new JButton("Stop Blend");
    static JButton saveImage = new JButton("Save Image To File");

    /*BtnStartBlendListener BtnStart = new BtnStartBlendListener();
     BtnStopBlendListener BtnStop = new BtnStopBlendListener();
     SaveImageListener SaveImg = new SaveImageListener();*/
    public Frame() {

        loadImages();
        initTimer();
        timer.start();
        //      timer.stop();

        pnlButton.add(btnStartBlend);
        this.add(pnlButton);
        pnlButton.add(btnStopBlend);
        this.add(pnlButton);
        pnlButton.add(saveImage);
        this.add(pnlButton);

        addListeners();
    }

    public void addListeners() {
        //start button actionlistener
        btnStartBlend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                initTimer();
                timer.start();

                System.out.println("Timer started");
            }
        });

        //stop button actionlistener
        btnStopBlend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // initTimer();
                timer.stop();

                System.out.println("Timer stopped");
            }
        });

        //Save button actionlistener
        saveImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Call to method to save image

                System.out.println("Save image clicked");
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        MeSmaller1 = new ImageIcon("MeSmaller1.jpg").getImage();
        MeSmaller2 = new ImageIcon("MeSmaller2.jpg").getImage();
    }

    public final void initTimer() {

        timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
        timer.stop();
        alpha = 1f;
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2Dim = (Graphics2D) g;
        // below sets the size of picture
        BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage(400, 600,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D gBuffI = buffImage.createGraphics();
        AlphaComposite aComp = AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha);
        // decides where images are drawn in JFrame
        gBuffI.drawImage(MeSmaller1, 28, 55, null);
        gBuffI.setComposite(aComp);
        gBuffI.drawImage(MeSmaller2, 30, 48, null);
        g2Dim.drawImage(buffImage, 10, 10, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        alpha -= 0.1;
        if (alpha <= 0) {
            alpha = 0;
            timer.stop();
            System.out.println("Morph Finished please restart.");
        }
        repaint();
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class PictureMorph extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PictureMorph() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Morph");
        setTitle("Facial Image Manipulation");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new Frame());
        // below set Frame Size around image
        setSize(380, 470);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PictureMorph picMorph = new PictureMorph();
                picMorph.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, It's not working but I think I may have my classes set up entirely wrong and they are not linking to each other as they should.....

Comment: The class I have as BtnStartBlendListener doesn't recognise initTimer from the frame class and also the 2nd line you put, I put as  btnStartBlend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    comes up with an error too.....

Comment: At present the timer starts the two images off blending automatically as well - this I want to change so the image starts blending once the startBlend button is pressed.

Comment: I've just extended the listener classes to Frame:- public class BtnStartBlendListener extends Frame implements ActionListener {     the class now at least recognises the initTimer in Frame class.

Comment: public class BtnStartBlendListener extends Frame implements ActionListener {

  JButton btnStartBlend = new JButton ("Start Blend");
  btnStartBlend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    initTimer();    Gary Read  this is what I have now there seems to be a problem this line :- btnStartBlend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

Comment: btnStartBlend is throwing an error because it isn't actually a button. Did you intent for this to be a button?

Comment: Yes at the top of the Frame class I have :-      JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
 static JButton btnStartBlend = new JButton("Start Blend");
 static JButton btnStopBlend = new JButton ("Stop Blend");
 static JButton saveImage = new JButton ("Save Image To File");

Comment: At the moment I have no errors and the application appears but now the blending of the images doesn't start automatically but unfortunately not at the touch of the start button either ...

Comment: how can I add my code on here for you to see where I'm upto @Gary Read ?

Comment: At the bottom of the Frame class there is this code :-    @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  alpha -= 0.1;
  if (alpha <= 0) {
   alpha = 0;
   timer.stop();
   System.out.println("Morph Finished please restart.");
  }
  repaint();
 }
}

Comment: There will be so much wrong with this :-/ be prepared - I'm trying to learn how to do this... :-)

Comment: Check the edit on the answer, the buttons now start/stop your timer.

Comment: This is fantastic, a huge improvement :-) I'm so grateful for your help. I had a lot of redundant code and the code you added makes pure sense :-) Thankyou very very much @Gary Read

Comment: Do I even need the 3 small classes BtnStartBlendListener, BtnStopBlendListener and SaveImageListener ? Last question I promise ..

Comment: Nope. You can use them, but you must use them correctly. You would do this if these listeners were going to be very long/complex. In that case you would want to separate the code into separate classes.

Comment: Ok thanks :-) I've ended up using just one class now to do everything :-)